# trigger code execution based on query results on node server

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

In a node server I run a query that can produce three different results:

1. return a row of data with status='A'
2. return a row of data with status='B'
3. return no rows

based on what the query returns, I have to perform different actions after. I.E. if scenario is 1 then update that record with status='B'. If scenario is 3 then insert a new record and so on.

I am looking for the correct syntax to use to check the three conditions.

My code is the following:

```
con1.query("<my query goes here>", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
```

If I want to check scenario 3 is it correct to check `if(result.length==0)`while to check scenario 2 or 3 `if(result[0].status=='A')` or `if(result[0].status=='B')`?
Will this always elaborate correctly? I am coming from PHP so I want to understand if my logics are correct:

```
con1.query("<my query goes here>", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if(result.length==0){
        //do something
    }else if(result[0].status=='A'){
        //do something else
    }else if(result[0].status=='B'){
        //perform another action
    }
});
```

Comment: *I run a query that can produce three different conditions* SELECT query does not fire triggers.

Comment: @Akina sorry, it's a typo. Reads "results". editing the question, thanks for pointing out